# If $f(z) = z^2 + 1$ we want to find the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ in $D^-(i;1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

What I have tried is to apply the maximum module to find out we can find maximum values on the edge of the disc. After doing that I tried $|z^2+1| = |(z+i)(z-i)| \leq (|z|+1)^2 \leq (|2i|+1)^2 = 9$ but I do not know if this is correct.

Comment: What's $D^-(a;b)$?

Comment: looks like maximum principle to me

Comment: @SaucyO'Path it is the closed disc with center in a and radius b

Comment: @User688539 it is what I am trying to use but I do not know if it is correct

Comment: It is certainly true that $\max\limits_{\lvert z-i\rvert\le 1}\lvert z^2+1\rvert\le 9$, and your proof is correct. However, $9$ is not the maximum. In point of fact, we could also prove that $\lvert z^2+1\rvert\le \lvert 2i\rvert^2+1=5$. Personally, I would try parametrizing the boundary and then maximize the resulting real-valued function as if we were working in $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By MMP the maximum is atttained on the boundary. Boundary points are of the type $z=i+e^{it}$ with $t$ real. For this $z$ we have $f(z)=-1+e^{2it}+2ie^{it}+1=e^{it}(e^{it}+2i)$. So we have $|f(z)| \leq (1)(1+2)=3$ and the value $3$ is attained when $z=2i$.

Comment: I did not realize that. Thank you so much, it is perfect :)